# How to show multiple categories per category in a collectionView in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, relationship, nspredicate

I need to show multiple categories per each category in Collection View as in the CoreData one category has many categories and the categories is set to be of type NSset 
when writing this line

```
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "category.categories == %@", (category?.categories!)!)
```

it throws an error 
CoreData: error: SQLCore dispatchRequest: exception handling request:  , to-many key not allowed here with userInfo of (null)

Comment: You can use `predicateWithBlock:` (but it's more expensive).

Comment: What is `categories`?

Comment: It is NSManagedObject ,a recursive relationship by which I have one Category that contains subcategories I need to show these subcategories in a collectionView

Comment: It won't work since the %@ in your predicate will include a `description` information of the object (array in your case). Fetch all of them then `filter { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use `NSPredicate`'s format string (but it's the cheapest solution - keep in mind) each time you need to filter while fetching.

You can use `predicateWithBlock` initializer:

```
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate { object, bindings -> Bool in
    guard let object = object as? Category else { return false }
    return object.categories == category?.categories
}
```

Or even `Array.filter`:

```
guard let allCategories = try? moc.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as? [Category] else { return }
let result = allCategories.filter { $0.categories == category?.categories }
```

Comment: when using the first code this error appears 'Unknown predicate type for predicate: BLOCKPREDICATE'